# fp.read not reading entire csv file

Tags: python, csv, email-attachments

I am attaching a csv file and sending it as an email.  Same code has been working for my other codes but in this weird case it truncates the data in csv.  Actual csv is 11 kb but attachment is of 8 kb. Actual file has 1400+ rows where as attachment only has some 1100 rows.

```
fp = open(path)
msg1 = MIMEText(fp.read())
print os.path.getsize(path)
attachment = msg1.add_header('Content-Disposition', 'attachment',     filename=name)
msg.attach(msg1)
print "Attached " + name
fp.close()
```

Issue is in this line of code - `msg1 = MIMEText(fp.read())`, but I'm not able to figure out a solution.

Comment: Suggest you find the _exact_ place the csv file is being truncated at and examine the data there to see if there's anything unusual about it. The default `_charset` for MIMEText is `us-ascii`, so any characters outside that range could be the cause.

Comment: fp.read() should be reading the whole thing, unless something stops it, so it is probably MIMEText stopping the read. Could be all sorts of things. Try to split the read and conversion into MIMEText into separate lines and see what happens.

Comment: Irrespective of what data is in the file, it truncates exactly at 8192 size and actual file size is 11523.  File just have cell numbers in it, no other data or special characters.

Answer (score 0):

We can't reproduce your problem without the original file, so this is only a guess.

The default behavior of `open('file_path')` is opening the file in text mode. If your CSV contains an EOF (end-of-file) character, then the `fp.read()` method may not return the whole file in some platforms.

Try to open the CSV in binary mode:

```
fp = open(path, 'rb')
```

[edit]

I'm unable to reproduce your problem.

```
>>> mt = MIMEText(open('/tmp/test_file.csv').read())
>>> len(mt.as_string().split('\n'))
1165
```

This has exactly the same number of lines of the original file plus the MIME headers:

```
$ wc -l /tmp/test_file.csv
1160 /tmp/test_file.csv
```

Please identify and closely inspect [the shortest program necessary to reproduce the problem](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) or this question will probably be closed because while similar questions may be on-topic here, as currently stated this one is unlikely to help future readers.

Comment: I tried but result remained same.  Irrespective of what data is in the file, it truncates exactly at 8192 size and actual file size is 11523.  File just have cell numbers in it, no other data.

Comment: Are you able to share the file so we can try to reproduce the problem?

Comment: Here is the file - https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B24sIrlQP0JsQjNSQ1BYaklMOXc/view?usp=sharing

It truncates at